# access non final variable from anonymous inner class

Tags: java, android

```
public class FoodTypeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

public FoodTypeAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_type_grid,
                new LinearLayout(context));
        holder = new ViewHolder();          
        holder.btnAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnItemAdd);
        holder.etQty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etfItemQty);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String quantity = holder.etQty.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(quantity);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mylist.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

static class ViewHolder {       
    Button btnAdd;
    EditText etQty;
}
}
```

In this code without make `holder` as `final` `Object` I can't access it from `OnClickListener`.

If I make it as `final` `Object` I can't initiate `holder` like `holder = new ViewHolder();`.

Now what can I do? Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thanks,
Guna

Comment: add a temporary final variable and assign it to `holder`, and use this temp var in your inner class.

Comment: Simply try this way :holder.btnAdd.setTag(holder.etQty.getText().toString()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around it by adding a temporary `final` variable before the anonymous class, and use that variable instead:

```
final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;    // <- added

holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String quantity = finalHolder.etQty.getText().toString();
        //                ^^^^^^^^^^^
        System.out.println(quantity);
    }
});
```

Or, you could make `holder` a member variable.

Comment: Ok friend, Get it, Thank you. Wait for 13 min. I will accept.

Answer (score 3):

You also could have simply adjusted the initialization of `holder` which reduced your code complexity by the way:

```
final ViewHolder holder;

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.food_type_grid,
            new LinearLayout(context));
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.btnAdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnItemAdd);
    holder.etQty = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etfItemQty);
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

Comment: `final` variable can't initialize this way.

Comment: That's simply not true.

Comment: I can't get you friend

Comment: `final String s;
if (new Random().nextInt() == 1) {
    s = "1";
} else {
    s  = "not 1";
}

System.out.println("s = [" + s + "]");`

Simply compile this and learn.

Comment: Your code works, but eclipse says like `The final local variable holder cannot be assigned. It must be blank and not using a compound assignment`. Thanks for your info.

Comment: Using my code above? Keep using this style in Netbeans/Intellij a long time.

Comment: added +1 for your kind info. It will be use me somewhere. Thanks once again. But I can't accept it as answer, because in future if anyone search for same problem with eclipse, this solution will not works. That's why. Thanks.